# Change URL when using ngx-translate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to change the URL when someone clicks on a choosen language using ngx-translate. I guess I should do it by subscribing to language change events and then modifying the current url to reflect the chosen language, Since I am a newbie I am not sure if I need a service to do it, or may be another way to solve it.

I want to change from this:

`https://amarello.cloud/es/`

To this:

`https://amarello.cloud/en/`

,depending on the choosen language.

This is my 'header.component.ts'

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//For translate language
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  menu: boolean = false;
  submenu: boolean = false;
  submin: boolean = false;

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) 
    { translate.addLangs(['es','en']);
      translate.setDefaultLang('es'); 
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  open() {
    if (this.menu == false) {
      this.menu = true;
    } else {
      this.menu = false
    }

    if (this.submin == false) {
      this.submin = true;
    } else {
      this.submin = false
    }
  }

  openSub() {
    if (this.submenu == false) {
      this.submenu = true;
    } else {
      this.submenu = false
    }
  }


  useLanguage(language: string): void {
    this.translate.use(language); 

    // this.translate.onLangChange().subscribe(trans => { 

    // })

  }
  

}
```

Comment: Why you want to change the url ? you already used changed language on translateService so think about how muck you need to change the url ? it's just a strange and oldfashioned solution. if you want to have the selected language saved use localStorage instead :)

Comment: If you want to change the URL and reflects the translateService you need to subscribe to changes of the URL, and once the URL is changed you can call the translationService method. [Check if this method will help you with detecting the URL change](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-with-examples/)

Comment: Hello Vitor!, I will check the link you share!

Comment: Hello Vitor, You can really tell me if I am wrong. Actually, I have the translation working pretty well, but 'ngx-translate' works in the same url and switches languages very fast, because it just calls '.json' files dynamically. (For example: es.json, en.json, pt.json) The thing I want to achieve is: Not really to detect router events, but to change the url, once the translation is done.  Also, You can check this link, since it shows the same problem as mine: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/776

Comment: Or maybe what you are trying to tell me is to change the Url first, and then with route change, somehow invoke the ngx translation?

Comment: Hello Vitor! I reformulate this question in order to get a better understanding. You may like to see it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70871271/change-angular-base-href-with-ngx-translate