# Change Angular base href with ngx-translate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have already implemented ngx-translate succesfully. Now, I want to change the base href of my Angular project, depending on the language I choose from my header menu.

Currently, my URL looks like this: "localhost:4200". Then, when you launch the project, it must show something like this: "localhost:4200/en" or like this: "localhost:4200/es", depending on the choosen language.

My index html has this:

```
<base href="/"/>
```

And my header component ts file has a function that changes the language using ngx-translate. As you can see, I tried to use 'replaceState' to show the choosen language in the URL, and it worked, but it disappears once I navigate to another route.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//For translate language
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core'; 
import { Router, Event, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
              private router: Router,
              private location: Location,
              ) 
    { translate.addLangs(['es','en']);
      translate.setDefaultLang('es'); 
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {



  }


  useLanguage(language: string): void {
    this.translate.use(language); 
    // alert(language);

    // location.replace("https://www.google.com");
    // return;


    const modified_path = language;
    this.location.replaceState(modified_path);

  } 
 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to achieve some kind of routing using base href. I would use base href only if I need multiple instances of my application. E.g. each of them in a subfolder.

Maybe you should give try on Angular Router (https://angular.io/guide/router-reference) if you want just one instance of the application handling different languages.
The idea is to have a route on the root level that represents the language and a language guard that ensures only valid languages are called.
This would look something like this:

```
const routes2: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':language',
        canActivate: [LanguageGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'home',
                component: HomeComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'some-page',
                component: SomePageComponent,
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/en',
    },
];
```

Comment: Hello Pateta, How can I solve this angular message?: Cannot find name 'LanguageGuard'. Do I have to install some package?

Comment: Hi @LuisAlejandroLópezdeAnda, you have to create such a guard yourself. It's like a function called every time a route changes. Here you can find some more information about the CanActivate guard: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate